# Printing multiple variables returned from single function

Tags: python, printing

Take a look at my code:

```
def convert_date(date_int):
    month = int(date_int / 1000000)
    date_int = int(date_int - 1000000 * month)
    days = int(date_int / 10000)
    date_int = int(date_int - 10000 * days)
    year = date_int
    return days, month, year


print("*This part*".format(convert_date(
int(input("Enter a date in the format MMDDYYYY: ")))))
```

That "*this part*" is the part that I dont know how to phrase to print a new line like this from user input “05102017”:

```
10/05/2017
```

Also I would appreciate if someone could suggest a better way to manipulate this user input

Comment: (1) you probably have an indentation error in your code. (2) please consider providing a minimal working example. (3) you should probably make best use of the *batteries-included* policy of Python and look into `time`, `datetime`, etc. packages.

Comment: You (hopefully) aren't getting an integer as input, but a *string* that you can split up using, for example, slicing: `day, month, year = date_int[:2], date_int[2:4], date_int[4:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use the [datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html).

But if you want to do it by simply manipulating a string from user input, you don't need the "convert_date" function. You can simply do:

```
input_date = input("Enter a date in the format MMDDYYYY: ")
print("{}/{}/{}".format(input_date[:2], input_date[2:4], input_date[4:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> date = int(input("Enter a date in the format MMDDYYYY: "))
Enter a date in the format MMDDYYYY: 05102017
>>> date = convert_date(date) # your function
>>> date
(10, 5, 2017)
>>> print("{}/{}/{}".format(date[0], date[1], date[2]))
10/5/2017
```